# Java - How To Have A Local Variable In A Superclass That Changes Only Through The Superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, super

The title might be a mess, but I don't know how to describe it better.

Basically, let's say that I have an abstract superclass, let's say `Person` that contains name, age and ID, and another class that extends from `Person`, `Members`.

I want to have a local variable in `Members` that stores how many objects were created from this class, and assign it to the ID variable.
I.E.
I created two objects from `Members`, m and m1. I want to automatically assign their ID for them, which increments by 1 each time an object is created.
`Members m = new Member("Name");`
`Members m1 = new Member("Name2");`
Then I call the method that prints the ID, two times for each object.
`m's ID is 1.`
`m1's ID is 2`

I went about to make this by having a local variable, `int numberOfObjects = 1;` and `objectID;`, and tried to make a new method
`SetNumber()`
`{`
`objectID = numberOfObjects;`
`numberOfObjects++;`
`}`

But, every time I make a new object, and call the method that shows it's ID, it sets it back to one.

So, can I make a local object, that doesn't reset every time I create a new object?
Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for the [`static` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). A word of advice: If the code should be thread-safe, we may want to use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

Comment: *FYI:* **Local variables** can only be declared inside methods (well, inside code blocks, actually), they cannot be declared by a class. Variables declared by a class are commonly referred to as **fields**, which can be either static *(class variables)* or non-static *(instance variables)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add static before the variable name.
Thanks to turing85 for the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85

Other answers were insightful, too.

Comment: Be careful and have fun, `static` can get out of hand if misusad but this is a very appropriate application for it.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate your child objects, just create a constructor for them that will assign a unique ID for them implicitly.

```
class Member{

    private String uuid;
    //your other variables below

    public Member(){
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        //other variables set up below   
    }
```

this will create a unique ID for every object you create.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand what you want to implement, but it felt like you wanted to add a unique ID to every object you make.

Comment: The querstion was not to generate a number/ist for euch instance, it was about a counter that globally counts how manny instances were crested. Creating a static variable using AtomicInt is the right way and increasing it on constructor calls.